# Unable to Scan table in Hbase using Java Client API

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to scan a table in Hbase and retrieve all records in it. This is the method which I use to scan table. I build project using Maven.

```
 public void getAllRecord (String tableName) {
    try{
        HTable table = new HTable(configuration, tableName);
        Scan s = new Scan();
        ResultScanner ss = table.getScanner(s);
        for(Result r:ss){
            for(KeyValue kv : r.raw()){
                System.out.print(new String(kv.getRow()) + " ");
                System.out.print(new String(kv.getFamily()) + ":");
                System.out.print(new String(kv.getQualifier()) + " ");
                System.out.print(kv.getTimestamp() + " ");
                System.out.println(new String(kv.getValue()));

                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These are my Maven dependancies

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-thrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.2-hadoop2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.96.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-maxent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

But the problem is when I run this method I receive following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/SoftValueSortedMap
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.SoftValueSortedMap

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by adding following dependancy to project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.96.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some jars are missing from your classpath. You either forgot to add util jar to classpath, or for some reason it was not included(could be that is was intentionally excluded with maven by  tag)